# Dividing packed 16-bit integer with mask using AVX512 or SVML intrinsics

Tags: c, intrinsics, avx, avx512

I am looking for a solution for dividing packed 16-bit integers with mask (`__mmask16` for example). `_mm512_mask_div_epi32` intrinsics seem to be good; however they only support packed 32-bit integers, which unnecessarily forces me to wide my packed 16-bit to packed 32-bit before using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_mm512_mask_div_epi32` isn't a real intrinsic; it's an Intel SVML function.  x86 doesn't have SIMD integer division, only SIMD FP `double` and `float`.

If your divisor vectors are compile-time constants (or reused for multiple dividends), see https://libdivide.com/ for exact division using a multiplicative inverse.

Otherwise probably your best bet is to convert to single-precision FP which can exactly represent every 16-bit integer.  If `_mm512_mask_div_epi32` does any extra work to deal with the fact that FP32 *can't* exactly represent every possible `int32_t`, that's wasted for your use case.

(Some future CPUs may have support for some kind of 16-bit FP in the IA cores, not just the GPU, but for now the best way to take advantage of the high-throughput hardware div/sqrt SIMD execution unit is via conversion to `float`.  Like one `__m256` per 5 clock cycles for Skylake `vdivps ymm` with a single uop, or one per 10 clock cycles for `__m512` with a 3-uop `vdivps zmm`)

Comment: I just realised that `_mm512_mask_div_epi32` does not have any corresponding asm, or is not a real intrinsic as you said. I guess it will be compiled into normal integer division asm and therefore cannot reduce the runtime. I will try converting to somes `vdivps` functions, then convert back to `epi32`.

Comment: @thnghh: I'd assume the internal implementation for `_mm512_mask_div_epi32` uses SIMD `float` or maybe even `double` to avoid rounding errors for 32-bit integers, if it's documented to always be exact.  Not unpacking to scalar for integer division!  It could also set the rounding mode to truncation to make sure a result doesn't get rounded up in magnitude before doing a truncating convert back to integer.  (AVX512 can do that efficiently with a rounding-mode override.)